# The excerpt doesn't add Read more

Tags: excerpt

I am confused about the behaviour of `the_excerpt()` and `get_the_excerpt()`.

My objective is to have a manual excerpt and display a continue reading.

I went through [this article](http://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-excerpt-teaser/), and apparently `the_excerpt()` is not meant for that.

So I'm trying `get_the_excerpt()` instead, and I still don't get the continue reading for some reason.

Again, the idea would be to display a manual excerpt and a continue reading link.

EDIT (forgot to add):
In my functions.php I have:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 1;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );


// Add more-link text to excerpt
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Continue Reading', 'baskerville') . ' &rarr;</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

I have tried in my content.php:

```
the_excerpt();
```

and

```
get_the_excerpt();
```

Comment: Discussions here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18995/discussion-on-question-by-trufa-the-excerpt-doesnt-add-read-more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the difference between the teaser and excerpt which is mistaken one for another in many case.

The `excerpt_more` filter that you are using will change the teaser `more text`, not the excerpt. The right filter for this is the `get_the_excerpt`. But it doesn't change the `[...]` of the excerpt, it gives you the ability to change the excerpt itself. So in this case you have to add the `Read more` to the excerpt and return that.

Here's the code -

```
// Add more-link text to excerpt 
function new_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) { 
    return $excerpt. '... <a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Continue Reading', 'baskerville') . ' &rarr;</a>'; 
} 
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

I will suggest you to read the article that you linked to your post again now. This will give you a better understanding of the difference now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, helped me a lot! Also, I had to implement the `the_excerpt` filter to return nothing to hide `[...]` for automatic excerpts: `add_filter('excerpt_more', '__return_false');`. Because my website has both; Manual and Automatic excerpts.